# Do up voted comments add to your reputation?

Tags: discussion

I recently had one of my comments up voted and my reputation didn't change but I did notice that my summary contained a link under "Helpful Flags"

I clicked on it and it lead to a mostly empty screen that just said "Flagged posts for DJM" and not much else.

Is this a bug? What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you observed, having a comment upvoted doesn't increase your reputation.

As for the Helpful Flags, you must have flagged something that was marked as helpful.

Comment: Although, if you had flagged a comment, that probably wouldn't be listed in the page, just mentioned in the sidebar box.

Comment: You might want to add a link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/192187 in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Helpful flags* are flags that have been considered useful from the moderator who handled them.
When you click on that link, and you are taken to an empty page, it means the flag was for a comment. When you flag a post (question, or answer), that page lists the posts you flagged with an indication of how the flag was considered (helpful, rejected, pending).